# clear the memory of Python script when the first run finish

Tags: python, memory, tk-toolkit

the case is that I have built a python script to scrape the web and generate a CSV file, and I have built a widget  using TK for this script, the problem I am facing that when I run the script for the first time it generates a CSV filename e.g(javaJobs.csv) with a 1000 job description, and if I don't close the widget and run it again with a new search term e.g(python jobs) I will have a new file name named pythonJobs.csv with 2000 job description, and the thing is that the script still has the first file in memory and that's why it has the second file has 2000(the first 1000 record is java Jobs description)
is there any way where I can clean the memory when the first run finish

Comment: try to clean ur variable after u finish ur tasks , try to use del to remove all vars from memory .

Comment: You're probably opening the file wrong. Try `with open(javaJobs.csv, 'w')`